# Relation of spectral multiplicity and commutant

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, spectral-theory, von-neumann-algebras

As we can see for, self adjoint operator $x$ in discrete spectrum if eigenvalues repeat $m$ times then a copy of $M_{m}(\mathbb{C})$ sits inside commutant of the vN algebra generated by $x$. So my question is for general spectrum $x$ how is this gonna work? In addition, how the direct integral decomposition shows up the multiplicty by dividing the spectrum on disjoint sets with $\{t \in \sigma(x):m(t)=k\}$? Kindly elaborate the details. I am missing the loopholes. Thanks in Advance!!!

Comment: How is what going to work? Whats the question? Do you want to read off the communtant of $x$ from the spectral properties of $x$?

Comment: Yes exactly. Finding commutant is the question using spectral properties of x?